# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header > Allow requests from production website to internal Spring application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I would like to test my application (Angular) in production. So I transfered all necessary files and I successfully started the Spring-Boot app (jar).
Angular is sending requests to 127.0.0.1 :

```
apiHost: 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/'
```

And the Configurer is like following :

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@CrossOrigin("*")
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Resource(name = "userService")
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationFilter authenticationTokenFilterBean() throws Exception {
        return new JwtAuthenticationFilter();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().
                authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/generate-token", "/signup","/config","/saveConfig/","/get/file/*").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
        http
                .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder(){
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("HEAD",
                "GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH"));
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "Cache-Control", "Content-Type"));
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

This gives the following errors :

```
Failed to load http://127.0.0.1:8080/salesStats: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://yzyzyzyz.com' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 503.
```

[image]

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: The OPTIONS request sent by the browser (the pre-flight request) comes back with a 503 (service unavailable) response. It's unclear why you want to test your code in production, but send requests to 127.0.0.1. 127.0.0.1 is your own development machine. Not production.

Comment: @JBNizet : but the Spring App is in the same server. So the Angular app should communicate with it internally. Right ?

Comment: No, not right. The angular JS files are on the server, and are downloaded by your browser, on your development machine, where the JavaScript code is executed. So, when code running on your your machine sends a request to 127.0.0.1 it sends a request to your machine. If the angular app and the backend REST services are served by the same server, you don't need any CORS, and you don't need to specify any protocol, host or port. Just send requests to `/salesStats`.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation and you have reason. I will absolutely test that ASAP.

Comment: @JBNizet: That did not work as it gives me a 404 Not Found error. I think that the port number is mandatory. Do you please have an idea ?

Comment: @JBNizet: And I should have a generic solution as we will send the package to our clients, and every client will deploy it in his server... Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: If you have a unique HTTP server serving both the rest services and the angular application, then it should work. If you don't, then you need to use the complete URL of your REST services. I have no idea how you deployed your angular app.

Comment: @JBNizet : The Spring app is running on the embedded Tomcat server (on port 8080). The angular app is running on the Apache server. And when I put something like `http://myproductionserver:8080/salesStats` I have a response.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you have two separate servers, one for the angular frontend, the other for the backend services, and code downloaded from Apache must send requests to Tomcat. In that case, you need the full URL of the TOmcat server. A much better design would be to configure Apache as a reverse proxy to the Tomcat server for all requests to the backend services: everything would be served from a single HTTP server, you wouldn't need CORS, and you wouldn't need to expose the Tomcat server to the internet.

Comment: @JBNizet: I think that I will go with the full URL solution and will try to let the user enter his server URL when getting the package and pass it into the Angular app. The second solution is not effective as I can not tell the clients to make such server modification. Thank you so much for providing such useful informations.

Comment: There is also another solution, is to implement the Angular app into the Spring app, I'm looking into this.